# Spring Boot JDBC Connection Pool testOnBorrow and testWhileIdle tracing and optimal settings

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, tomcat, jdbc

We have a Spring Boot Micro-services Architecture, the problem is the connections in pool sometimes become stale and a /health check fail, This is how I am going to address the issue, by setting testOnBorrow so that connection is tested before being returned.

Following properties should eventually fix the problem

```
spring.datasource.tomcat.testOnBorrow=true 
spring.datasource.tomcat.validationQuery=SELECT 1 
spring.datasource.tomcat.validationInterval=30000
spring.datasource.tomcat.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.tomcat.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=30000
spring.datasource.tomcat.minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=60000
spring.datasource.tomcat.validationQuery = SELECT 1
```

I am trying to make sure all this happening right, before I promote this change.
I don't see **SELECT 1** in any logs even the connection is Idle for a long time.

So there are 2 questions:

1. Is there a way to see the validation query executed at certain times in java logs / db logs so that it ensures the problem is fixed.
2. What should be the optimal settings for connection validation for testOnBorrow (validationInterval) and testWhileIdle (timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis) as mentioned in [Tomcat JDBC Connection Pool Documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html)